# Why does my UIScrollView not work?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uiscrollview, scroll

I have placed a `UIScrollView` in a `ViewController` in `IB` and gave the view the `tag:1`. In `viewDidLoad:`, I have this code:

```
UIScrollView *scrollView = (id)[self.view viewWithTag:1];

scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
scrollView.opaque = NO;

[scrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];
[scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 800)];
```

I have a slider and a label in the `ScrollView` just to see if it scrolls, but it doesn't scroll at all. I get to change the `backgroundColor` to for example `yellowColor`, but it doesn't scroll. Is there a method or action i have to add? Please help! :)

Comment: your code working fine dear some where else you went wrong once check.is there any view with same tag or like that.

Comment: Well, i suspect that it is the fact that i have an initial viewController where i press a tableviewCell which leads me to the view with the scrollview. Can this have something to do with thhis?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem not long ago, but this did the trick.

Use   -(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    ...
    }

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated  {

    [super viewDidAppear:YES];

    scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    scrollView.opaque = NO;

    [scrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];

    [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 800)];

    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Also declare the UIScrollView in your header

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try Like this

```
UIScrollView *scrollView = (id)[self.view viewWithTag:1];
scrollView.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460);
[self.view addSubview:scrollView];
scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
scrollView.opaque = NO;
[scrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];
[scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 800)];
```

because when the scroll view height cross the current view height then only its get scrollable.

Answer (score 0):

```
scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

change this to something bright like red or green for testing.

```
UIScrollView *scrollView = (id)[self.view viewWithTag:1];
scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

also make sure your scrollview isnt nil (after obtaining from `[self.view viewWithtag:1]`. otherwise the code seems OK

**EDIT**

select scroll view in interface builder > go to attributes editor > tick scrolling enabled

[image: enable scrolling]

Comment: The background changes, i have tested that. Shall i set the scrollView to self?

Comment: OK. if using interface builder select your scrollview in IB > attributes inspector > tick "scrolling enabled"

Answer (score 0):

here may be its problem with set TopBar of `UIView` with `UINavigationBar` from xib and also BottomBar of that... Here from XIB first select main `UIView` after click on `Attribute Inspector` after in Simulated metrics set NavigationBar as a TopBar and after set frame of `UIScrollView` in `XIB`.

try with bellow code it will worked ..

```
[scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 844)];
```

Comment: @HenrikLP also add this line at last  [scrollView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

Answer (score 0):

try to add this code in `viewWillAppear`

```
UIScrollView *scrollView = (UIScrollView *)[self.view viewWithTag:1];
scrollView.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 400);
scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[scrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];
[scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 800)]; 
[scrollView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
```

hope will help you